# Django 'POST" returning 'Subscriber' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to send a POST Request to add a 'Subscriber' to my database. The POST Request goes through without error.

***I am Posting this***

```
{
    "email":"email@app.com","campaign":1
}
```

***and it returns***

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "email": "email@app.com",
    "created_at": "2022-08-02T19:49:55.509018Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-08-02T19:49:55.509018Z",
    "campaign": 1
}
```

***The ID is 2 because it is the second POST I have made***

This is my Subscriber Class

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(to = Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=('-created_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title()
```

*** These are my current Serializers.py***

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = "__all__"


class SubscriberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Subscriber
        fields = "__all__"
```

When I go to the ***Admin Panel at /admin*** and I click on my Subscribers that is when I get the error

AttributeError at /admin/Campaigns/subscriber/
'Subscriber' object has no attribute 'title'

And I am unable to view the information posted.

***If I remove***

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title()
```

From my Subscriber Class, it works, however, it is displayed as
Subscriber object (1)
In the database, rather than the ***email name***

So,

1. Do I have to remove the

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.title()
```

From my Subscriber Class?

2. How do I make the object name in the database the email itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscriber doesn't have a `title` field or attribute, hence the error. You need to return one of it's attributes or an attribute of the campaign (which does have a `title` attribute), e.g.:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.email

# or

def __str__(self):
    return self.campaign.title
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry it took me too long to upvote you, my points had been too low to upvote, but I came back for you. Haha, I'm homeless so I really appreciate the assistance.